# How to query for documents with invalid references using spring data mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

Let's assume that we have collection A which references collection B through a field called "bref", which is an array of ObjectId's from collection B. For collection A, there are 4 possible situations that I am interested in:

1. At least one bref array item points to a valid document from B.
2. The bref array is empty.
3. The bref array does not exist (is therefore null).
4. None of the items from bref array points to a valid B document.

In spring-data, using a MongoRepository, I was able to resolve the situations from above as follows:

1. getByBrefLike(ObjectId brefId, Pageable pageable)
2. getByBrefIsNullOrBrefIsLessThanEqual(String[] emptyString, Pageable pageable)
3. getByBrefIsNullOrBrefIsLessThanEqual(String[] emptyString, Pageable pageable)
4. Not solved yet.

Questions:

1. Is it possible to detect the documents from A that points to non-existent references from B, using spring-data mongodb repository like I did in the above example?
2. How would you prevent that situation from ever happening? (is it possible to define some constraints)?
3. If a spring-data solution is not possible, what would a mongodb solution look like?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Pageable<T> findByBrefNotIn(List<ObjectId> brefs, Pageable, pageable)
```

Comment: I don't think that will work, as I have no idea what are the items in the brefs list from your response. I need to dynamically detect the "orphan" values. To be more concise, if we have a list of books, and each book has a list of author id's attached, I need to detect the book records that contains at least one invalid author id from the authors table (the author might have been deleted, and the delete operation was possible because there was no constrain imposed upon the two collections).

Comment: In the question you asked "None of the items from bref array points to a valid B document." . Now you say "records that contains atleast one invalid ". These two are not exactly the same. Either the question is incorrect or the example you gave :)

Comment: There is not so much difference, in fact. Detecting the records where at least one reference id is invalid would be the perfect solution, but detecting at least the records where none of the reference ids points to a valid record in the other table would also be sufficient. But your answer did not come even close to any of these scenarios. I have two collections A and B and A has an array of ids that points to (valid or not) records from B. I need to DYNAMICALLY get these records from A table and display them.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong here, for point 1, you want to dynamically get all the records from A which has At least one bref array item points to a valid document from B. Then in this case which brefId are you passing to getByBrefLike(ObjectId brefId, Pageable pageable). I am just curious how this is working?

Comment: No, that's not what I want. I have a tree structure with authors and a grid view with books. When an author is selected, I refresh the grid and display all his books. Books are stored into table "books", and authors into table "authors" and each book has an array of authors associated. All is fine, except when a book: 1. does not have an author set; 2. all his "authors" array elements points to authors that don't exist. I want to aggregate 1 and 2 cases, in order to display an artificial author tree item. When this item is clicked, all "author-invalid" books must be shown in the grid.